# What determines Entity Framework DbMigration operation ordering?

Tags: entity-framework

When scaffolding new migrations in code-first Entity Framework the `Up` and `Down` methods are populated with `DbMigration` operations such as `CreateTable`, `CreateIndex`, `AddPrimaryKey`, etc.

What determines the order of these operations and can it be customised?

Comment: It's the order in which your code executes it. In the implementation of the `Up()` method (for example), if you first call `CreateTable()` then `CreateIndex()` then (obviously) `CreateTable()` will be called first.

Comment: I understand that, but what generates the actual sequence of operations? What determines the ordering in which `CreateTable`, `CreateIndex`, etc. appear in the `Up` method?

Comment: You determine that. In order to perform `CreateIndex` and `AddPrimaryKey`, you need to `CreateTable` first.

Comment: The sequence of operations is generated when I run the `Add-Migration` command. I define the entity classes and their relationship but Entity Framework generates the migrations. The database technology I'm using is Oracle and it is very picky with the ordering of operations in the `Up` and `Down` methods, to the point that I have to rearrange the generated sequences manually in order for it to work. That's the core of my question. How can I affect the ordering of the auto-generated sequence of operations. Not manually in the `Up` and `Down`, but maybe using data annotations or fluent api.